# Markdown: extra markup within code samples?

Tags: markdown

If you are within a code sample, Markdown (basic, as well as: Markdown Extra and Github versions) ignores any and all markup (MD itself, HTML). If you need to manually highlight something within a code sample -- forget about it.

Use case: in your code sample you need to emphasize a specific line. Ideally you should be able to wrap the line with _lines of code_ or <em>lines of code</em> and then nicely highlight in CSS with something like:

```
pre em {background-color: yellow}
```

There doesnot seem to be a way to do such thing with current MarkDown processors? :(

Comment: How would MD know what it should parse and what not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw HTML in markdown.  So, just do something like this:

```
<pre><code>
boring line
<em>exciting line</em>
</code></pre>
```

Of course, you have to remember to escape any `"`, `&`, and `<` characters as entities. If this is tedious, you can use markdown to do it, then paste the HTML it produces (with your added em tags) into your markdown source.

Comment: Thanks, John. Sounds like it would work as the last resort, but kindof defeats the whole purpose of using MD, in the first place. Still hoping that there may be a better solution. Thank you.